# How to set preferred resolver in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I set additional resolver in sbt configuration, whic proxies maven central, to avoid some traffic in CI server.

Anyway when project builds I see in logs that libraries are downloaded from maven central or typesafe, but I see these packages are also present in my proxy repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Proxy-Repositories.html) is the guide to configure proxy repositories.

Basically, you need to add a file ~/.sbt/repositories with your repos. For example:

```
[repositories]
  local
  my-ivy-proxy-releases: http://repo.company.com/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  my-maven-proxy-releases: http://repo.company.com/maven-releases/
```

Additionaly, you need to tell sbt to override the default and project repos with the ones described in that file. This is done by passing the following option to the launcher: `-Dsbt.override.build.repos=true`. It could be added to the `SBT_OPTS` environment variable.

It's worth to add that one can use `-Dsbt.repository.config=<path-to-your-repo-file>` flag if file ~/.sbt/repositories can't be created.